# ViewStat very weird behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, viewstate

I am using devexpress controls in my page, but that is not the problem.

Here is what happens, I have created a property in the page with a get only, this property will retrieve query string value from a ViewState. I store the value in the ViewState on page load event which is enclosed in !IsPostBack. After I store 
note that i have put an update panel on my master page.
I searched the net and found that ViewState values are never stored in callbacks, I don't know if that is the reason. Here is my code:

```
    public partial class _Default : BasePage
{
    private Int64 RequestId
    {
        get
        {
            return (Int64.Parse(ViewState["RequestId"].ToString()));
        }
    }

    protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check for security
        base.Page_Load(sender, e);

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GetQueryString();
            gridBind();
        }
    }

    private void GetQueryString()
    {
        string requestId = this.Request.QueryString["RID"];
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(requestId))
            ViewState["RequestId"] = Int64.Parse(this.Server.UrlDecode(requestId))
        else
            ViewState["RequestId"] = 0;
    }
  }
```

I edited the question, the first problem i had was due to the IE7 stupidity, but nevertheless ViewState after each postback is null. I tried to use the EnableViewState but it's always null. It's the same in any page I use in my solution. We can't use ViewStates at all. There is definitely something wrong.

Comment: Where did you invoke property "RequestId"

Comment: I invoke it in the private method tha binds the grid. gridBind();